# Do I need to import core-js/stable and regenerator-runtime/runtime when using @babel/preset-env with useBuiltIns:'usage'?

Tags: build, babeljs, babel-preset-env, core-js

I use babel `7.8.3` together with `@babel/preset-env`, `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` and `corejs: 3`. The documentation for `@babel/preset-env` is not clear to me.

Do I need to add the following lines at the top of my entry file or is it done automatically by babel?

```
import 'core-js/stable';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to add import code by yourself when use `usage`.

And no more need to manually include the regenerator-runtime helper when compiling generators after `babel/core >= 7.18`

Answer (score 0):

According to babel-preset-env [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-entry) you should import those modules by yourself

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a typo in the description. I meant `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` not `useBuiltIns: 'entry'`